# plotly 'splom' type does not show scatter points

Tags: r, plotly

I'm only copy-pasting the splom tutorial code found here: https://plot.ly/r/splom/ but getting an output with no plotted points:
[image]

code:

```
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/iris-data.csv')
pl_colorscale=list(c(0.0, '#19d3f3'),
                   c(0.333, '#19d3f3'),
                   c(0.333, '#e763fa'),
                   c(0.666, '#e763fa'),
                   c(0.666, '#636efa'),
                   c(1, '#636efa'))

axis = list(showline=FALSE,
            zeroline=FALSE,
            gridcolor='#ffff',
            ticklen=4)

p <- df %>%
    plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(
        type = 'splom',
        dimensions = list(
            list(label='sepal length', values=~sepal.length),
            list(label='sepal width', values=~sepal.width),
            list(label='petal length', values=~petal.length),
            list(label='petal width', values=~petal.width)
        ),
        text=~class,
        marker = list(
            color = as.integer(df$class),
            colorscale = pl_colorscale,
            size = 7,
            line = list(
                width = 1,
                color = 'rgb(230,230,230)'
            )
        )
    ) %>%
    layout(
        title= 'Iris Data set',
        hovermode='closest',
        dragmode= 'select',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(240,240,240, 0.95)',
        xaxis=list(domain=NULL, showline=F, zeroline=F, gridcolor='#ffff', ticklen=4),
        yaxis=list(domain=NULL, showline=F, zeroline=F, gridcolor='#ffff', ticklen=4),
        xaxis2=axis,
        xaxis3=axis,
        xaxis4=axis,
        yaxis2=axis,
        yaxis3=axis,
        yaxis4=axis
    )
p
```

session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.3.1     factoextra_1.0.5 shiny_1.3.2      plotly_4.9.0    
[5] ggplot2_3.2.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        cellranger_1.1.0  ggpubr_0.2        pillar_1.4.1     
 [5] compiler_3.5.0    later_0.8.0       viridis_0.5.1     tools_3.5.0      
 [9] dendextend_1.12.0 digest_0.6.19     jsonlite_1.6      tibble_2.1.3     
[13] gtable_0.3.0      viridisLite_0.3.0 pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.3.4      
[17] igraph_1.2.4.1    cli_1.1.0         rstudioapi_0.10   crosstalk_1.0.0  
[21] ggrepel_0.8.1     yaml_2.2.0        gridExtra_2.3     withr_2.1.2      
[25] dplyr_0.8.1       httr_1.4.0        htmlwidgets_1.3   grid_3.5.0       
[29] tidyselect_0.2.5  glue_1.3.1        data.table_1.12.2 R6_2.4.0         
[33] purrr_0.3.2       tidyr_0.8.3       magrittr_1.5      scales_1.0.0     
[37] promises_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6   assertthat_0.2.1  mime_0.7         
[41] colorspace_1.4-1  xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.5.1      labeling_0.3     
[45] lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Am I missing some graphics software to get sploms to work?

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: @Chelmy88 I don't get an error message.

Comment: Start with restarting your session. I cannot reproduce the error even after mimicking your session info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNcdw.png

Comment: Restarting the session doesn't fix it. Neither does re-installing the package.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Really annoying.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, turned out to be related to Rstudio rather than a code issue. Opening in a new window (in browser) solved it for me.